# htaccess Rewrite Rule to /user/home

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I need to process this kind of URL:

```
localhost/twitter/user/home
```

My rewrite rule is:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/?$ index.php?url=$1 [NC,L]
```

`^([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/?$ index.php?url=$1` refers to the pattern

`[NC]` refers to no case

`[L]` flag causes `mod_rewrite` to stop processing the rule set

I need to get the url in the form of:

```
$_GET['url'] = user/home
```

But I am getting:

```
$_GET['url'] = user
```

Got Resolved

```
   RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+/[^/\.]+)/?$ index.php?url=$1 [NC,L]
```

Comment: Have you tried: http://www.generateit.net/mod-rewrite/index.php ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/?$ index.php?url=$1 [NC,L]
```

to

```
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/([^\.]+)/?$ index.php?url=$1 [NC,L]
```

and you should get `user/home`

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this is caused by grouping in your rewrite rule. Anything between the first `()` is set to `$1`. To access the second part (`$2`) of the url (`home` in your case, anything between the second `()` in your rule), you could

```
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/?$ index.php?url=$1&action=$2 [NC,L]
```

or rewrite your rule to

```
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+/[^/\.]+)/?$ index.php?url=$1 [NC,L]
```